# DragEvent.ACTION_DROP Error

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

When I calling delete method in Drop action the application giving "app not responding"

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
          ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          owner.removeView(view);
          FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) v;
          container.addView(view);
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          app.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    DeleteWithID(id_db);    
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
              });
          break;
```

Comment: 'app not responding` is not an error. It means you are doing too many thing on the main UI which blocks it and that time you get ANR message.

Comment: But if I remove the DeleteWithID(); app is running well

Comment: Thats what I am talking about.You must be doing some heavy task  in `DeleteWithID()` method.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` to do the task in the background.

Comment: Thanks I do like you say,It's worked for me :)